# Quit app after Toast message dissapears

Tags: qml

I've found fantastic [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879266/make-toast-in-android-by-qml) on creation of `Qt/QML` implementation of [Android Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html). I am trying to upgrade it after `Toast` disappears some signal is emmited - I want to quit simple `Qt/QML` app. Here is `ToastManager`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Column
{
    id: root

    z: Infinity
    spacing: 5
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    signal signalQuitApp;

    property var toastComponent

    function show(text,
                  duration)
    {
        var toast=toastComponent.createObject(root);

        toast.selfDestroying=true;
        toast.show(text,
                   duration);

        signalQuitApp();
    }   // show

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        toastComponent=Qt.createComponent("Toast.qml");
    }   // Component.onCompleted
}   // Column
```

The result is, if I click some button inside `QML` application, it quits before `Toast` animation is over. How do I emit signal **AFTER** `Toast` dissapears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the answer by @ayberk-Özgür you will need to modify `Toast.qml` to emit the signal when it is done.

```
id: root
signal toastFinished()

// ...

    onRunningChanged:{
        if (!running) {
            root.toastFinished();

            if (selftDestroying)
                root.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Before you show the toast you connect to that signal

```
toast.toastFinished.connect(Qt.quit);
toast.show(text, duration);
```